# Django select_related with join on multiple fields

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a somewhat complex database in django. It makes extensive use of partitioned tables. I have had some problems before with django and partitioned tables but so far I have found satisfactory solutions to all of my problems.

My newest Problem concerns a foreign key relationship between two partitioned tables. I have a model called Event with a submodel called MonitorEvent that houses some additional information  for this type of events. The, for my question, important fields of the models are:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    id PK, (automatically added)
    ts timestamp

class MonitorEvent(Event):
    event_ptr_id FK -> Event (automatically added)
    ts_copy timestamp
```

Both tables are partitioned by month using the timestamp. The timestamp, however is not part of the PK, since django does not allow multi-field PKs. (I have tried using joined PK fields without success [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706043/django-save-object-based-on-pk-and-another-field)) Therefore I need a copy of the timestamp in the subclass to allow for a partitioned table of the subclass.

Now to my problem: I would usually select all Events and MonitorEvents by executing:

```
Event.objects.all().select_related('monitorevent')
```

(I would, of course, add some filters as to not select all available events.) To my understanding this would result in a SQL Query like:

```
SELECT * FROM event LEFT JOIN monitorevent ON event.id = monitorevent.event_ptr_id;
```

which should join all event table partitions with all monitorevent table partitions. I would actually want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM event LEFT JOIN monitorevent ON event.id = monitorevent.event_ptr_id AND event.ts = monitorevent ts_copy;
```

which should allow the query planner to make use of the partition scheme to speed up the query.

Is there a possibility in django to write a custom Manager that modifies the default select_related to include an additional field in the ON condition of the query?

Another possibility for me would be to write a custom raw query that does the select_related manually, however according to this question [Django select related in raw request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328251/django-select-related-in-raw-request) this does not seem to be possible except from the manual proposition made in the question.

Of course I could also add the additional fields to the original event model and delete the submodel which would eliminate the problem altogether, but that would be my least favorite solution.

I am using Django 1.5 in combination with a postgres DB.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I think you've already found the answers, that it's not very possible in Django ORM